# Change root profile picture

Tags: gnome3

I would like to change the default root's picture:

[image: root piture]

I tried adding Icon entry in `var/lib/AccountService/users/root`, but when I reboot the file is overwritten and the icon row is deleted. I was thinking of changing this icon, directly, with one of my choice.

Where can I find it? I'm running Kali 2.0 Sana

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding the Icon property to the `/var/lib/AccountService/users/root` and it didn't work for me either. For some unknown reason the content of the config file gets overridden.

After some additional googling I found out that GDM also checks for the existence of `$HOME/.face` or `$HOME/.face.icon` files if no image is defined in the config file. So once I added the picture to `/root/.face` GDM picked it up right away. Just make sure it's in the right format, mine is PNG 96x96.